# Question on finding a law which simplifies a product

Tags: sequences-and-series

how do you find the general law which simplifies the product:

$(1-1/4)(1-1/9)...(1-1/n^2)$

i have no idea how to do this the only thing i could do is take blind guesses, how are you meant to solve this kind of problem?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "simplifies the product?" Are you looking for a formula? A limit? Please be clear about what you're trying to do.

Comment: a formula i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seek a formula for the equation

$$f(n)=\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$

As each term is the difference between two square, we may factor this to get

$$f(n)=\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)$$

Writing these with common denominators gives

$$f(n)=\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1}{k}\right)\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k+1}{k}\right)=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}\frac{(n+1)!}{2(n!)}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Wel $(1 - \frac 1{n^2}) = (1-\frac 1n)(1+\frac 1n) = \frac {n-1}n\frac{n+1}n$

So
$(1-1/4)(1-1/9)...(1-1/n^2)$ =

$(1+\frac 1n)(1 + \frac 1{n-1}) ...... (1 +\frac 12)(1-\frac 12)....(1-\frac 1{n-1})(1-\frac 1n) =$

$(\frac {n+1}n\frac n{n-1}\frac {n-1}{n-2}....\frac 43\frac 32)(\frac 12\frac 23 \frac 34 .... \frac {n-2}{n-1}\frac {n-1}{n}) =$
$\require{cancel}$
$(\frac {n+1}{\cancel{n}}\frac {\cancel{n}}{\cancel{n-1}}\frac {\cancel{n-1}}{\cancel{n-2}}....\frac {\cancel{4}}{\cancel{3}}\frac {\cancel{3}}2)(\frac 1{\cancel{2}}\frac {\cancel{2}}{\cancel{3}} \frac {\cancel{3}}{\cancel{4}} .... \frac {\cancel{n-2}}{\cancel{n-1}}\frac {\cancel{n-1}}{n}) =$

$\frac {n+1}2\frac 1n =  \frac {n+1}{2n}$.

Comment: The telescoping here looks more complex than it needs to be. Can't you just say that $$\frac12 \underbrace{\frac 32 \frac 23}_1 \underbrace{\frac43 \frac34}_1 \underbrace{\frac54{\cdots}}_1 \cdots \underbrace{{\cdots}\frac{n-2}{n-1}}_1 \underbrace{\frac{n}{n-1} \frac{n-1}{n}}_1 \frac{n+1}{n} = \frac12 \frac{n+1}{n} $$

Comment: If you think that is simpler.  I see the nesting as simpler.